# Why can't I see 'date_time_original' in all files?

Tags: metadata, photos

I have a process at work in which I have to request clients to send photos of their cars to check a certain attribute. To send the photos, they have an on-line contact form (in its **'desk version'** & **'mobile version'**). Every submission of the contact form with pictures, automatically creates a ticket in a ticketing system and those tickets are then checked by an agent of the company.

One of the things we need to verify in the photos, is the date when they were taken (because I need photos to be recent). With this purpose, I've been using a metadata tool and checking **'date_time_original'** or **'create_date'**.But, I'm having problems to identify this piece of data with certain files.

I'm not sure if it depends on the file extension, the file name or the version of the contact form the clientes are using to submit the photos.

About the different versions of the contact form, I made a test and this is what happens:

- when using the **mobile version** to attach the photos, they are transformed to **'image.jpg'** (if I take the photos directly from the contact form) or **'randomname.jpeg'** (if I attached pictures previously taken). In both cases, **'date_time_original' / 'create_date'** are not among the metadata.
- when using the **desk version** (I have to send the photos form my cell-phone to my computer), the photos are transformed to **'IMG_XXXX.jpg'**. In this case, I have **'date_time_original' / 'create_date'** among the metadata.

I'd be grateful if you could help me understand the issue.

Comment: So, when you take a pic with metadata, and upload it to the mobile version of the contact form the output has no metadata? We do not have access to the mobile version of the form so it'll be very very difficult for us to diagnose that problem and impossible to fix it.

Comment: it sounds like the problem is how the photos are being submitted, they are losing some of their information and would probably need the developer to take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Phones cameras usually add full metadata to the photos they take.

However, when sending an image, many phones give the user the option
of either sending the original image at its original size, or of
sending a reduced version of the image.

Users that would like the sending to be faster and use less of
their bandwidth, will opt for a smaller version, which means
that the image will be transformed and the metadata will be lost.

I believe that this is the reason that your desktop photos, which are
always transferred as-is, differ from photos sent by some mobile users.